# command execution time from code vs direct query

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

This is very weird.  Piece of straigthforward code

```
        using(SqlConnection
        {//open connection 
            using(SqlCommand
            {//Specified parameters and SP name
                using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                    // Parse it and return an object.

                        return new MyObject
                                   {
                                      prop1 = (int)reader["column1"]
                                      ...

                                      propN=reader["columnn"].ToString()
                     }
```

may take up to 3 minutes to execute, while executing same SP from Management Studio runs in less than a second!

This code runs on another server.  I also found that Sql Profiler reports several millions of reads if executed from code, while less than 5000 reads when executed in Studio.

I haven't an inkling why would that be.  Any help is appreciated.
P.S. Isn't execution plan is bound to a SP meaning no difference what client was used to run it?

Comment: Probably the code inside the inner `if (reader.Read())` is not so neutral as you think.

Comment: One thing you might try is running SQL Profiler when executing from Management Studio and also when executing the code, see if there's any difference in what each of them are explicitly requesting from the database.

Comment: Code inside it straightforward as in edited question.

Comment: David, in both cases you can see exec MyProcedure @parameter1=@value1 etc.  Calling from code duraion column is 67000, while calling from Studio is only about 380.  Reads are also very different.

Comment: [This article](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) might be a good place to start your investigation

Comment: Are you using the same credentials in both instances? If not, set up a connection in SSMS to use the same login as the app.

Comment: Yes, I do.  Actually it seems to be something else

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an answer but at least it solved it ;)
Running SQL profiler with capturing execution plan (as insinuated by David), I found that they differed for the first and second scenario.
Than I hypothesized that there could be a problem with stats/indices - optimizer had very poor options.  Rebuilding indices solved the problem, and both ways execute close to each other (in time).  So if you experince this - check for indexes fragmentation and stats last updated.